# how to resize iphone keyboard?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, user-interface, keyboard

I am developing a program in which I have to change the size of the keyboard according to the size of a `UITextView`, either increase or decrease. How can I do this?

Comment: You would need a custom keyboard. But maybe you are talking about preventing the keyboard from being on top of the textView?

Comment: @Jano please tell me how to customized key board?

Comment: By custom keyboard I mean that you need to implement one from scratch, which is obviously a lot of work.

Comment: Can I open my view in place of keyboard.

Answer (score 3):

it's impossible in standard SDK.